# PHP: How to convert HTML template to string by executing logic inside HTML?

Tags: php

Is there a way where in I can read an HTML file in a PHP script which can provide me the contents of file as string output replacing the variables and executing some logic?

Basically, I am looking for a php function which can serve as a template engine. I am coming from Python, Django so I am looking for something similar to render function in django.

Comment: From what you wrote, it appears [this library](https://github.com/speedmax/h2o-php) would do what you need.

Comment: sure you can use `file_get_contents()` function. it will return all content as a string than `str_replace()` to replace some place holder

Comment: eval() is what you are looking for, but is quite insecure... There are a lot of template libraries like smarty, blade where you can work similar as with django templates

Answer (score 0):

Try using [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) function by passing the html template vars You want to be replaced in that template.

I suggest You consider using template engine like [Smarty](http://www.twig) or [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).